# NUCLEO-L432KC timer PWM frequency problem: PSC and ARR values not resulting in desired PWM frequency

Tags: stm32, pwm, c, stm32cubeide

I have been trying all day to use timer 1 channel 1 of a nucleo-L432KC (with a [STM32L432KC](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32l432kc.pdf) MCU) to generate a PWM signal of frequency 50 Hz (pulse width 20 ms). I tried many, many, MANY different combinations of prescaler and ARR register values but it doesn't work. When I measure the output signal with an oscilloscope I don't get signals with a pulse width of 20 ms. They are always much smaller (µs) and I don't understand why.

This was all with a default SYSCLK of 72 MHz. Later I tried to lower the frequency for the timers APB2 to something like 2 MHz or 8 MHz and also tried many combinations of the register values. None of them work. Even wildly changing the register values didn't change the result which was wrong and never a 50 Hz PWM signal.

I also change the CCR1 register directly in my code which is supposed to be the duty cycle and it has to be minimum 0 and maximum the value of ARR but when I do that the pulse width for ARR/2 is really small and not 50% like I expect. However when I do CCR1->half of 65535 independent of what ARR is.

I'm out of ideas and really frustrated. Idk what to do. Is the board broken then?

Please help.

EDIT: I have the screenshots now but not of the oscilloscope output because I'm not there anymore. The problem is that following all tutorials and trying to do stuff the proper way I didn't find a single configuration or timer register set of values that give me a 50 Hz PWM signal. I don't know what else to try.

Timer configuration
[image: This is the formula I've been using]
[image: Timer configurations]

Clock configuration:
[image: Clock configuration]

At some point I thought to maybe lower the frequency of the timers so I lowered the APB2 frequency but I'm really new to this so I don't really know why it would be correct or fix it either. I used these settings then:
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please show some source code or cubeMX screenshots so that others can have a look at your settings. Especially the APB2 clock and the TIM1 config are of interest. If you know how to calculate the ARR and CCR values, then the problem lies probably in a bad clock config.